# ANTL4 Parser (Flat parser vs Structor parse) for Language Translator

Tags: performance, parsing, grouping, antlr4

Over the last couple of months, with the help of members from this site, I have been able to write (Phase 1) a Lexer and Parser to translate Lang X to Java. Because I was new to this topic, I opted for a simple **line by line**, parser and now it's able to parse around 1000 language files in 15 minutes with a small number of errors/exceptions and circa 1M lines of code, with the problems being isolated to the source files not the parser. I will refer to this a flat parsing, for want of a better expression.

Now for Phase 2, the translation to Java. Like any language, mine has Data Structures, Procedures, Sub-routines, etc and I thought it best to alter the parser from below (for simplicity I have focussed on the Data Structure (called TABLE)):

```
// Main entry point of the program
program
   : executableUnit+ EOF
   ;
   
// Execution units (line by line)
executableUnit:
    |   itemBlockStart
    |   itemBlockEnd
    |   itemStatement
    |   tableHeader
;

itemBlockStart: BEGIN;
itemBlockEnd:   END;
tableHeader: // A TABLE declaration statement
    TABLE atom LETTER (atom)*
;
// Item statement
itemStatement:
        // Tables with Item statements
        ITEM atom+
// Base atom lowest of the low
atom:
        MINUS? INT              #IntegerAtom
    |   REAL_FORMAT             #RealAtom
    |   FIX_POINT               #FixPointAtom
    |   (MINUS | EQUALS)? NAME DOT?     #NameAtom
    |   LETTER                  #LetterAtom
    |   keywords DOT?           #KeywordAtom
    |   DOLLAR atom DOLLAR      #DollarAtom
    |   hex_assign              #HexItem
    ;
```

to this:

```
// Execution units (by structure)
executableUnit:
        tableStatement
    |   itemStatement
;

// Table statement, header and body
tableStatement:
    tableHeader (itemBlockStart | itemBlockEnd | itemStatement)*;
```

Before we go any futher, TABLE and individual ITEM statements can occur anywhere in the code, on their own (Java output would be public) or inside a Procedure (Jave output would be private)

Imagine my dismay (if you will) when the parser produced the same number of errors, but took 10 times longer to parser the input. I kind of understand the increased time period, in terms of selecting the right path. My questions for the group are:

1. Is there a way to force the parser down the TABLE structure early to reduce the time period?
2. Whether having this logical tree structure grouping is worth the increased time?

My desire to move in this direction was to have a Listener callback with a mini tree with all the relevant items accessable to walk. I.e. If the mini tree wasnt inside a Procedure statement is was public in Java.

Comment: With your change, the grammar ambiguous. The parser cannot easily determine when tableStatement ends and the next executableUnit begins. I think on a parse error, there is a cascade of backtracking, peeling off one itemStatement, retry and refail, and again. Try adding a semantic predicate to stop the greedy *-operator on itemStatement. Actually an interesting example I need to note and test in analysis of a grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what performance difference you are referring to (presumably, the difference between the "line by line" parser, and this, full file, parser. (???)

A few things that "jump out" about your grammar, and could have some performance impact:

1 - `itemBlockStart: BEGIN;` and `itemBlockEnd:   END;`.  There's no point in have a rule that is a single Token.  Just use the token in the rule definition.

2 - You are, probably unintentionally, being **VERY** relaxed in the acceptance of `itemStartBlock` and `itemStopBlock` in this rule (`tableStatement: tableHeader (itemBlockStart | itemBlockEnd | itemStatement)*;`).  This could also have performance implications.  I'm assuming in the rest of this response that `BEGIN` should appear at the beginning of an `itemStatement` and `END` should appear at the end (not that the three can appear in any order willy-nilly).

Try this refactoring:

```
// Main entry point of the program
program
   : executableUnit+ EOF
   ;
   
// Execution units (line by line)
executableUnit:
    |   itemStatement  # ItemStmt
    |   tableHeader    # TableHeader
;

tableHeader: // A TABLE declaration statement
    TABLE atom LETTER atom*
;

// Item statement
itemStatement: // Tables with Item statements
    BEGIN ITEM atom+ END
;

// Base atom lowest of the low
atom:   MINUS? INT              #IntegerAtom
    |   REAL_FORMAT             #RealAtom
    |   FIX_POINT               #FixPointAtom
    |   (MINUS | EQUALS)? NAME DOT?     #NameAtom
    |   LETTER                  #LetterAtom
    |   keywords DOT?           #KeywordAtom
    |   DOLLAR atom DOLLAR      #DollarAtom
    |   hex_assign              #HexItem
    ;
```

admittedly, I can't quite make out what your intention is, but this should be a step in the right direction.

As Kaby76 points out, the greedy operator at the end of the `tableHeader` is quite likely to "gobble up" a lot of input.  This is **partly** because of the lack of a terminator token (which would, no doubt, stop the token consumption earlier than not having a termination token.  However, your `atom` rule seems to be something of a "kitchen sink" rule that can match all manner of input.  Couple that with the use of `atom+` and `atom*` and there's quite the likelihood of consuming a long stream of tokens.  Is it really your intention that any of the `atom`s can appear one after the other with no structure?  They appear to be pieces/parts of expressions.  If that's the case, you will want to define your grammar for expressions.  This added structure will both help performance and give you a MUCH more useful parse tree to act upon.

Much like the structure for `tableStatement` in your question's grammar, it doesn't really represent any structure (see my recommendation to change it to `BEGIN ITEM atom+ END` rather than accepting any combination in any order.  The same thought process needs to be applied to `atom`.  Both of these approaches let ANTLR march through your code consuming a LOT of tokens without any clue as to whether the order is actually correct (which is then very expensive to attempt to "back out of" when a problem is encountered).

Comment: Hi Mike, My intention was to move away from a flat - line by line parser, which completes in circa 10 mins (its fast) to a more structured tokenised tree. I believed I needed to move in this direction because when I come to translate the tree to Java (using JavaPoet for example) I would have MORE _context_. E.g. If the TABLE was contained inside a Procedure, then the resulting Java output would be PRIVATE to the procedure. Conversely if it wasnt then its PUBLIC. I can potentially see other ways of understanding context, but doing it this way seemed to leverage more from Antlr4.

Comment: P.S. I did change // Table statement, header and body to
tableStatement:
    tableHeader (itemBlockStart itemStatement+ itemBlockEnd)? But this didnt seem to help. My hope esd to provide a definitive end/terminstion statement.

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer.  In short, your grammar seems very "relaxed" about what it would accept as valid input and contains greedy constructs.  This combination will have major performance issues.  It will also not provide a very useful parse tree (what will you do with "a list of `atom`s"?).   If you intend to gradually add more rules to cover that structure, it's going to be painful and perform poorly until you have enough definition that ANTLR can recognize an error in your input quickly, report it, and recover.

Comment: Just a guess.. It looks a bit like you are trying to get a grammar "kind of working" on the whole input, and then refine the rules from there (hence, things like `atom+` and `atom*` and no termination token for the table statement.). I'd suggest that you may have a better experience developing things from the "bottom up".  Making sure all your tokens are correct, then getting the rules right for proper expressions, etc.  and testing subsets of code against those rules.  Then build up from there.  Having ANTLR verify the structure and build good parse trees is it's main value.

Comment: Hi Mike, 1) I have been relaxed in certain respects for a reason:

Comment: I can tolerate this leve of ineffieiciency. I have however, determined that if I give ANTLR a better termination / end statement : From a TABLE perspective (only)...I can change the grammer as per my previous post with no lose of speed.

Comment: Apologies I took too lomg to respond. reason: I simply dont care what comes next..this is a 50 year old language and floating point precisiion (i dont need to understnad) at this point.

Comment: My last comment is related to the atom+ or atom* coments. I can tolerate that inefficiency.

Comment: MC I do agree with your statement about relaxed grammer having a direct effect on the performance. I have tightened up on the grammer and its having benefits. However, I would like to know whether moving in to this more structured construct is worth it when it comes to the befitis for translation/context?

Comment: If, as I assume, this is the parser for your source language then I would expect having ANTLR build as fully structured a parse tree as possible, can't be anything but beneficial.  It should be much easier to visit the various Context objects and spilt out destination source.  Just collecting a list of tokens, really just gives you the benefit of the Lexer.  (I can't really imagine doing it WITHOUT a fully formed parse tree (well, I can *imagine*, but it's not pretty))

Comment: Thx Mike, Happy New Year.  If I am honest I knew that would be the answer. For the example I provided I have now extrapolated up the use of atom+ and atom* to give ITEM and TABLE alternatives in the parser that have just about equalled the line by line methodology in terms of speed of processing. I have also gone further and grouped the IFEITH, IFOR and IF statements and their sub-trees. The problem now is that for certain input files the parser never finished. Different problem, can we close this thread now?